# Inserting JS command into console of .aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, command

Is it even possible to inject JS commands into page created with ASP.NET?[image]

Everything seems to be undefined even tho it exists.

[image]

EDIT: It's not working. Should it be working?

[image]

EDIT 2: The element I am trying to get is inside the  tag, I can reach elements outside of it.

Comment: Maybe you should provide us your full scripts on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASPX has nothing to do with outputting content to the web console. It's done by javascript. Use

```
Console.log(); //Put what ever you want inside the brackets
```

to output anything to the console. If you want to add a popup kinda thing use the `alert()` so it will give a popup with the data upon execution.

Comment: try using `document.getElementById('elementid')` and console.log it!

Comment: still undefined. Is it possible that there are some restrictions that prevent me from doing this?

Comment: Also there would be and error if jQuery wasn't working

Comment: does your elemetn reside inside an iframe?

Comment: yes it does. This command seem to fetch it. window.frames[2].document.getElementById('lbl_icount').innerHTML

Comment: I figured that! :) good that you figured that on your own! :)